# Golang google pubsub so slow when publish message

Tags: go, google-cloud-pubsub

Hi I am new with google pubsub, why so slow when publish message to topic? Sometime it only takes 20-30ms, but sometimes can takes 200 ms - 1 second. I am using docker on GKE.
There is something wrong in my code?
I don't know how to solve it. Please help me

**Environment**

golang:1.13.1 Docker on GKE

cloud.google.com/go/pubsub v1.3.1

**Code**

```golang
package publisher

import (
        "google.golang.org/api/option"
    "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"
    "context"
    "errors"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Publisher struct {
    Client *pubsub.Client
    Topic  *pubsub.Topic
    config Config
}

func (pub *Publisher) initClient(ctx context.Context, project string, opts ...option.ClientOption) error {
    pubSubClient, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, project, opts...)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    pub.Client = pubSubClient

    return nil
}

func (pub *Publisher) initTopic(ctx context.Context, topic string) error {
    pubTopic := pub.Client.Topic(topic)

    if isExist, err := pubTopic.Exists(ctx); err != nil {
        return err
    } else if !isExist {
        return errors.New("Topic " + topic+ " is not exists in this project")
    }

    pub.Topic = pubTopic

    return nil
}

func InitializeWithConfig(project string, topic string, opts ...option.ClientOption) (*Publisher, error) {
    var ctx = context.Background()
    pub := Publisher{
        config: config,
    }

    if err := pub.initClient(ctx, project, opts...)); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if err := pub.initTopic(ctx, topic); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &pub, nil
}

func (pub *Publisher) Publish(msg string, eventAttr map[string]string) (*string, error) {
    var ctx = context.Background()

    result := pub.Topic.Publish(ctx, &pubsub.Message{
        Data:       []byte(msg),
        Attributes: eventAttr,
    })

    id, err := result.Get(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &id, nil
}

func main() {
       pub, err := InitializeWithConfig("project-name","topic-name",option.WithGRPCConnectionPool(10))

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

       startAt := time.Now()
       _, err := pub.Publish("testing", nil)

    duration := time.Now().Sub(startAt).Milliseconds()
    fmt.Printf("%vms", duration)

}
```

Comment: not sure if there is anything wrong in your code, but if you want to improve throughput, you might want to batch publish your messages https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#batching